# How to set custom gradient background for UIButton?

Tags: ios, uibutton, gradient, cagradientlayer

I would like to create a custom UIButton gradient background. I attached some picture about the requirements.
[image]
[image]

But my gradient background is not as I expected.

[image]

My question is how to set the position or location to the gradient? (from top to center and then center to bottom).

Here is my code:

```
- (void)setBlueShiningLayer {
    CALayer *buttonLayer = self.layer;
    [buttonLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [buttonLayer setCornerRadius:5.0];
    [buttonLayer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [buttonLayer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:153.0f / 255.0f green:153.0f / 255.0f blue:153.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor];

    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    [gradientLayer setBounds:self.bounds];
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            (id) [UIColor colorWithRed:129.0f / 255.0f green:151.0f / 255.0f blue:179.0f / 255.0f alpha:0.8f].CGColor, // top
            (id) [UIColor colorWithRed:111.0f / 245.0f green:133.0f / 255.0f blue:162.0f / 255.0f alpha:0.4f].CGColor, // center
            (id) [UIColor colorWithRed:95.0f / 245.0f green:118.0f / 255.0f blue:151.0f / 255.0f alpha:0.4f].CGColor, // center
            (id) [UIColor colorWithRed:75.0f / 245.0f green:99.0f / 255.0f blue:133.0f / 255.0f alpha:0.8f].CGColor, // bottom
            nil];

    [gradientLayer setPosition:CGPointMake([self bounds].size.width / 2, [self bounds].size.height / 2)];
    [gradientLayer setColors:colors];
    [buttonLayer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];

    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.3f]];
}
```

Comment: Did my answer sort your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the gradient layer is spacing out the colours evenly. That's why you're getting the effect that you're getting.

To fix this you can use the `locations` property of `CAGradientLayer`.

Like this...

```
gradientLayer.locations = @[@0, @0.5, @0.5, @1.0];
```

TBH, the easiest way to do this with a `UIButton` is to use an image.

Just create a button image with the gradient and border that you want and then add it ass the background image.

You can create a resizable image if you need to use it at different sizes.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now, but I have to  set the last position to 0 too. And I agree with you to use images, but the designer send me the  RGB instead of the pictures :)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift - Version 4.2**

```
@IBOutlet weak var gButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let topGradientColor = UIColor.red
    let bottomGradientColor = UIColor.yellow

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    gradientLayer.frame = gButton.bounds

    gradientLayer.colors = [topGradientColor.cgColor, bottomGradientColor.cgColor]

    //Vertical
    //gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    //gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)

    //Horizontal
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)

    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]

    gButton.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```